# how to play a video for each item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video.js

I have a list of multiplem items (`.brand-item`), each `li` has a different video inside.

I'm trying to play a video for each `li` but with the code I have, when I click inside each `li` it opens the sound of all videos, so it is playing all of them.

How can I rewrite my code to play only the video for each `li`?

My code, I'm using `video.js`:

```js
$(".brand-item-info").click(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('.fullscreen-video video').each(function() {
      var player = videojs($(this)[0]);
      player.currentTime(0);
      player.play();
      player.muted(0);
    });
  });
  $(this).next(".fullscreen-video").fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<li class="brand-item">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="brand-item-info"></a>
  <div class="fullscreen-video">
    <video id="my-player<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="none" playsinline loop muted data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "fill": true, "preload": "auto" }'> 
        <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php the_field("brand_-_project_vimeo_distribution_link") ?>">
      </video>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon-close icon-close-video"></a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use contextual information, aka `$(this)`, so that you only target the `.fullscreen-video` element that comes right after the clicked button:

```
$('.brand-item-info').click(function(){
    var $fullscreenVideo = $(this).next('.fullscreen-video');
    var video = $fullscreenVideo.find('video')[0];
    var player = videojs(video);

    player.currentTime(0);
    player.play();
    player.muted(0);

    $fullscreenVideo.fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to inject the `video` value into the `videojs()` function instead of `$(this)[0]` which would select the anchor element.

Comment: I don't know why but this only opens the video, it doesn't play it

Comment: @z-1881 I made a mistake: the player instantiation code should be `videojs(video)` :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help you :

```
       $(".brand-item-info").click(function (e) {

            var fullScreenVideoElement = e.target.nextElementSibling;
            var videoElement = fullScreenVideoElement.querySelector("video");

            var player = videojs(videoElement);
                player.currentTime(0);
                player.play();
                player.muted(0);

            $(fullScreenVideoElement).fadeIn();
          
        });
```

I try to find the right elements from clicked target.

Comment: Try to use either jQuery or vanilla JavaScript functions. Combining them should mean that either you don't need jQuery or you are not using it right.

Comment: You are right. I just edited the code to make it work for z-1881 . Of course you don't need jQuery but as it was already in the original question i reused some parts =)